# SharePoint Task List Funtionality

Tags: task-list

Do SharePoint’s task lists have the capability to display documents that due for certification/modification within a given timeframe? For example, it would pick up that a document has an annual certification date of 12/31/15 and would display the document 2 months prior as a reminder on 10/31/15.

Answer (score 0):

They can, there is nothing automatic about this. You would need to create entries intot he list, with a link to the file, and create a workflow that sends out a reminders on fixed dates prior to the recertification.